# What are Mass Rate(∆v)/∆v, Mass Rate(Isp)/Isp and time of burn(MR)/MR graphs?

Tags: delta-v, rocket-equation, specific-impulse, mass-fraction, taylor-text

I have some problems about Tsiolkovsky's Rocket Equation and some graphs.

Firstly, I didn't get what I can do with Rocket Equation formulas as seen below,

[image: equations]

Also, what these three graphs try to mean? Can someone explain the relations between these values?

[image: Mass Ratio(∆v)/∆v and Mass Ratio(Isp)/Isp graphs]

[image: Time of the burn(Mass ratio)/Mass Ratio graph]

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These graphs show different visualizations of the Tsiolkovsky rocket equation:

[image]

(source: [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation))

The equation relates change in velocity to engine efficiency and the propellant mass consumed.

For example the first graph shows that to achieve a delta-v of 30,000 m/s with an engine that has an $I_{sp}$ of 1000, you will need a mass ratio of 21.  Tripling the  $I_{sp}$ to 3000 hugely reduces the mass ratio required for the same delta-v to ~ 2.77.

[image]

The second graph just swaps the placement of specific impulse and delta-v but uses the same equation.

**Update**: After looking into it, I am dubious about Equation 3.37. See discussion in my answer to [Some exercise questions about Tsiolkovsky's Rocket Equation and Thrust Equation](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/35891/some-exercise-questions-about-tsiolkovskys-rocket-equation-and-thrust-equation)  There are good burn time equations in answers to this question [How do I calculate a rockets burn time from required velocity?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27375/how-do-i-calculate-a-rockets-burn-time-from-required-velocity) .

Finally, the first equation in your question is derived from the rocket equation by dividing through by $I_{sp} * g_0$, taking the inverse natural log of both sides, and multiplying the result by $m_f$ (equivalent to your $M_{empty}$).

The second equation in your question is derived from the burn time equation 3.37 in the same manner.  **Update:** But I am still dubious about equation 3.37.

Comment: Hey! This answer is fit to my question perfectly. I have another question. I could not understand the meaning of specific impulse. It's an efficiency measurement of a rocket engine, that's ok, but in the description of it and where to use it, it confuses my head. Can you give me a brief explanation of specific impulse, please?

Comment: Glad it helped! That's already been asked, and you can read about it here: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/9344/why-do-we-use-the-gravitational-acceleration-at-the-earths-surface-when-calcula

Comment: Alright, thanks so much @Organic Marble. I will not forget to giving positive feedback your answer and comments, I need 15 reputations to do it. Have a good day!

Comment: You are welcome and welcome to space stack exchange.